# can't save persian char (utf-8) in mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql, database, unicode, utf-8

I get following link from the google http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=auto&tl=fa&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=3&uptl=fa&alttl=en&sc=1&text=hello which contain some persian alphabets, so I wanna save it into mysql database with following code :

```
pageurl = new URL("http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=auto&tl=fa&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=3&uptl=fa&alttl=en&sc=1&text=of");
t = pageurl.openConnection();
t.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(t.getInputStream()));
preparedStatement2 = con.prepareStatement("update `en_db` set `meaning` = ? where `id` = ?");
preparedStatement2.setString(1, in.readLine());
preparedStatement2.setInt(2, id);
preparedStatement2.executeUpdate();
in.close();
```

but it will save something wrong in database,like

```
[[["??","of","",""]],[["preposition",["??","?? ????","?? ???","?? ????","?? ???","?","?? ????","?? ????","?? ???","??????"],[["??",["of","from","in","by"]],["?? ????",["of"]],["?? ???",["on behalf of","of","for"]],["?? ????",["about","on","concerning","of","toward","in re"]],["?? ???",["of","with"]],["?",["of"]],["?? ????",["of"]],["?? ????",["of"]],["?? ???",["of"]],["??????",["by","via","per","of","with"]]]]],"en",,[["??",[5],0,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["of",4,,,""],["of",5,[["??",1000,0,0],["?? ??",0,0,0],["??????? ??",0,0,0],["?? ??",0,0,0]],[[0,2]],"of"]],,,,6]
```

if I print it by `System.out.println` it will show

```
[[["از","of","",""]],[["preposition",["از","از لحاظ","از طرف","در باره","در جهت","ز","از مبدا","از منشا","در سوی","بوسیله"],[["از",["of","from","in","by"]],["از لحاظ",["of"]],["از طرف",["on behalf of","of","for"]],["در باره",["about","on","concerning","of","toward","in re"]],["در جهت",["of","with"]],["ز",["of"]],["از مبدا",["of"]],["از منشا",["of"]],["در سوی",["of"]],["بوسیله",["by","via","per","of","with"]]]]],"en",,[["از",[5],0,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["of",4,,,""],["of",5,[["از",1000,0,0],["ای از",0,0,0],["استفاده از",0,0,0],["را از",0,0,0]],[[0,2]],"of"]],,,,16]
```

How should I solve it?

Comment: What's the encoding of your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the other answers, and: your database connection URL should be something like:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

This ensures that the driver communicates in UTF-8 too.

***Important***

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(t.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

I have seen in Stack Overflow answers to google Translate that the header was given with a language to receive the correct encoding, but everything is already fine.

Answer (score 0):

You table fields are defined with a character set which does not support Persian characters (most probably, `Latin1`)

You need to convert them into a character set which supports them:

```
ALTER TABLE en_db MODIFY meaning VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

(for each field individually), or

```
ALTER TABLE en_db CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

(for all fields).

Answer (score 0):

Check how your MySql DB is configured.

Take a look on the following article: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html

The encoding can be configured either globally (per DB) or per table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
.................
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```